# How can I switch words in a column around?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am given a .csv file and asked to use pandas to answer some questions. 
In one of the question it ask to find the three most popular name. But asked to print there first name followed by there last name. I understand how to do that but how can I have a space between the first and last name for example ' John Smith' insted of 'JohnSmith'.

My code is this:

```
works['ConductorName'] = works['ConductorName'].str.replace(r'(.+),\s+(.+)',r'\2\1')
results = works['ConductorName'].value_counts()

display(results.to_frame().head(3))
```

This prints data as this:

```
AlanGilbert  695
JoshuaGersen 45
RobFisher    35
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Source DF:

```
In [38]: df
Out[38]:
  ConductorName  val
0   AlanGilbert  695
1  JoshuaGersen   45
2     RobFisher   35
```

Solution:

```
In [39]: df.ConductorName.str.replace(r'([a-z])([A-Z])', r'\1 \2')
Out[39]:
0     Alan Gilbert
1    Joshua Gersen
2       Rob Fisher
Name: ConductorName, dtype: object
```

But you can simply change your code as follows:

```
works['ConductorName'] = works['ConductorName'].str.replace(r'(.+),\s+(.+)',r'\2 \1')
#                                                                              _^_
```